# A tool that keeps track of assets a site is loading?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm performing a site review for one of our properties and it's a spectacular mess. One of the issues is that there are 123 files in the .js folder, and I'm not certain how many of them are used because each page on the site has it's own head calling specific dependencies.

I'm wondering if there is a chrome plugin that will keep track of the dependency files/names I'm loading as I bounce around a site. Or perhaps there's a method I can use that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Chrome Developer tools, you can go under the Network tabs and see what files are being requested from the server. You can then sort them by type to get a glance at the scripts being loaded.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools screenshot]

Comment: I appreciate the response. I'm aware of this, but the sheer amount of files being loaded on any given page makes compiling a list an extremely arduous task. I was hoping to expedite it, but if I have to do it the hard way, I'll do it the hard way.

Comment: What is that you want to do exactly, then?

Comment: I thought there may already be a tool that will create a perpetual list of resources as you browse a site. I can just see how useful it would be to keep appending loaded resources to a running list.

Comment: You mean "list" as in "text file of lines with urls"? Because devtools *do* show a list.